# How to print std::optional < T > for any T assuming `std::ostream << T()` is well defined?

Tags: c++

I am trying to migrate an existing (largish) code base using `boost::optional` to use `std::optional`.  BOOST has optional_io.hpp.  No such thing exists for std::optional

This has to work with boost unit test as well

Comment: Have you tried doing the same as what optional_io.hpp does?

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::optional<T> const& opt)
{
    return opt ? os << opt.value() : os;
}

int main()
{
    std::optional<int> oi = 8;

    std::cout << oi << '\n';

    oi.reset();

    std::cout << oi << '\n';

    oi = 5;

    std::cout << oi << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
8

5
```

Only print the value if it exists (then return the stream), otherwise just return the stream.

Comment: What are the pros/cons of declaring this in the global namespace?  It works, but is it the right thing to do?

Comment: @zrb You get to control what goes into the global space of your application. However I would not put this into a library so as to force it on other people. Not unless the specific purpose of that library was to provide this functionality - like `optional_io.hpp` does.

Comment: This approach doesn't work for boost unit test.  I think ADL doesn't look in the global namespace

Answer (score 3):

You could simply read [optional_io.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/boost/optional/optional_io.hpp) and do the same thing. That said, they have chosen an approach that can be highly misleading. The following example illustrates the issue:

```
boost::optional<std::string> demo1 = "--";
boost::optional<std::string> demo2 = boost::none;
std::cout << demo1 << ' ' << demo2;
```

Output:

```
--  --
```

To reduce chance of confusion, I recommend something like this instead:

```
template<class Out, class T>
Out&
operator<<(Out& out, std::optional<T> const& v)
{
    if (v)
        out << "optional(" << *v << ')';
    else
        out << "nullopt";
    return out;
}
```

It doesn't solve all problems, but seems like a more reasonable default to me.

Comment: Just a tip. If you try to use this function operator<< in place in some namespace. E.g. all your code inside `namespace my_project{}`. Then you may fail to find your templated function. Example when your `operator<<` function is in namesapce you need to add `using common::format::operator<<;`. When in global scope: `using ::operator<<;`